# How to force any decimal value (be it part of a type or not) generated with fscheck to be within a certain range?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, f#, fscheck

I'm using [fscheck](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck) to write some unite tests and I would like to narrow down the range of decimal automatically generated and that regardless of the parameter I'm passing. What I mean by that is that let's say I have the types below:

- `decimal`
- `DecimalHolder`
- Nested records containing decimal fields
- DU with cases with decimal fields

**Without having something to define an arbitrary for each single type**, just that down the line in the generation if there a decimal it must say be between `0` and `300,000`.

```ml
module Tests

open Xunit
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote


let addDecimals a b: decimal =
   a + b

[<Property>]
let ``test adding two decimals`` a b =
    let actual = addDecimals a b
    let expected = a + b
    test<@ actual = expected @>

type DecimalHolder =
    { Value: decimal }

let addDecimalHolders a b =
    { Value = a.Value + b.Value }

[<Property>]
let ``test adding two decimal holders`` a b =
    let actual = addDecimalHolders a b
    let expected = { Value = a.Value + b.Value }
    test<@ actual = expected @>

type DecimalStuff =
    | Value of decimal
    | Holder of DecimalHolder
    | Holders of DecimalHolder list
    // Whatever

etc.
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually the Arbitrary definition works recursively across parameters types was enough:

```ml
module Tests

open Xunit
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

type NotBigPositiveDecimalArbitrary =

    static member NotBigPositiveDecimal() =
        Gen.choose (1, 500)
        |> Gen.map (fun x -> decimal x)
        |> Arb.fromGen

let addDecimals a b: decimal =
   a + b

[<Property(Arbitrary = [| typeof<NotBigPositiveDecimalArbitrary> |])>]
let ``test adding two decimals`` a b =
    let actual = addDecimals a b
    let expected = a + b
    test<@ actual = expected @>

type DecimalHolder =
    { Value: decimal }

let addDecimalHolders a b =
    { Value = a.Value + b.Value }

[<Property(Arbitrary = [| typeof<NotBigPositiveDecimalArbitrary> |])>]
let ``test adding two decimal holders`` a b =
    let actual = addDecimalHolders a b
    let expected = { Value = a.Value + b.Value }
    test<@ actual = expected @>
```